# Can i copy file into jar

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource

Can I copy files into jar? 
Im getting error on this one:

```
BufferedImage img;
img = ImageIO.read(MatrixMaker.class.getResourceAsStream("/resource/"+filemlg));`
```

I want to make arrays filled up with RGB form images . I need this images in rs folder because function need this getResourceAsStream.

Comment: _Into_ or _from_? See the examples cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Comment: Could you explain what you try to do and please also include the error you get. A stacktrace might be useful. Maybe you could even provide a runnable sample so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What goal do you want to accomplish by doing this?
The first will help us help you identify the issue. The second will allow us to help you find a possibly better solution.

Comment: I want to make arrays filled up with RGB form images . I need this images in rs folder because function need this getResourceAsStream.

Comment: @MackTank So you want to add those pictures as resources in order to use them at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the input stream and convert to `BufferedImage`

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource/"+filemlg);
BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(is);
```

Comment: here it is `MatrixMaker`

Comment: @Tom The magic is in `this` - which (in part) ensures it is not called from a static context.  The thing is, we need the context class loader for locating application resources, but the failure to use `this` means we might end up with the 'boot' class loader.